# error using rauth in app engine (Permission denied)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-plus, rauth

I have a app engine app, using oauth and [rauth](http://rauth.readthedocs.org), i'm trying to use Facebook, Twitter and google to login.

When i run it locally works, but in production i got this error, but only with google plus, with facebook works fine.

> ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in **call**
>       rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in **call**
>       rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
>       return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in **call**
>       return handler.dispatch()
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/handler.py", line 11, in dispatch
>       webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
>       return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
>       return method(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/loginToken.py", line 69, in get
>       ep=log.getTokenData(code)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/conect.py", line 34, in getTokenData
>       session = self.getSession(conf,code)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/conect.py", line 61, in getSession
>       session=conf.get_auth_session(data=self.getData(code), decoder=json.loads)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/rauth/service.py", line 556, in get_auth_session
>       session = self.get_session(self.get_access_token(method, **kwargs))
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/rauth/service.py", line 541, in get_access_token
>       r = self.get_raw_access_token(method, **kwargs)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/rauth/service.py", line 518, in get_raw_access_token
>       **kwargs)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/rauth/session.py", line 358, in request
>       return super(OAuth2Session, self).request(method, url, **req_kwargs)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/rauth/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/rauth/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-getwell/login:1.379942143707124638/code/oauth/rauth/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>   ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))

I have the billing enabled, and in the yaml have added the ssl library (latests)

This is the code with wich i make the oauth calls

```
class login():    
    def __init__(self,tipo=tipoConexion.Google, redirect_uri =  'http://map.getwell.care/'):
        self.__tipo=tipo        
        self.config=config.data(redirect_uri)        

    def getAuthorizationURL(self):
        conf=self.getConfig()
        params=self.getParams()
        url = conf.get_authorize_url(**params)
        return url

    def getTokenData(self, code):
        ''' Get the data that i need from the provider '''
        conf=self.getConfig()
        session = self.getSession(conf,code)
        tokenizerConcreto=JsonReader.factory(self.__tipo,session)
        email=tokenizerConcreto.getEmail()[0]
        urlPic=tokenizerConcreto.getPicture()[0]
        logueado=not tokenizerConcreto.getEmail()[1]
        return logueado, urlPic, email

    def getParams(self):
        params=None
        if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Google:            
            params = self.config.GooglePlusScope
        if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Facebook:
            params = self.config.FacebookScope
        return params

    def getConfig(self):
        conf=self.config.googlePlus
        if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Facebook:
            conf=self.config.facebook
        if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Twitter:
            conf=self.config.twitter
        return conf

        def getSession(self,conf, code):
            session=None
            if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Google:
                session=conf.get_auth_session(data=self.getData(code), decoder=json.loads)
            else:
                session=conf.get_auth_session(data=self.getData(code))
            return session        

    def getData(self,code):
        data=None
        if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Google:
            data={
                 'code' : code,
                 'redirect_uri': self.config.redirect_uri,
                 'grant_type':'authorization_code'
             }#
            logging.info("GetWell: Data previo al error: %s" % data)
        if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Facebook:
             data={
                 'code' : code,
                 'redirect_uri': self.config.redirect_uri,                  
             }    
        if self.__tipo==tipoConexion.Twitter:
            raise NotImplementedError
        return data
```

and this is the code when i got the secrets keys

```
class tipoConexion():
    Google=0
    Facebook=1
    Twitter=2

class data(object):
    def __init__(self, url =  'http://map.getwell.care/'):
        self.redirect_uri=url

    def getURL(self):
        return self.redirect_uri

    @property
    def twitter(self):
        return OAuth1Service(
            consumer_key='imnotatwitterman',
            consumer_secret='ilovevine',
            name='twitter',
            access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
            request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1/')

    @property
    def facebook(self):
        return OAuth2Service(
            client_id='someID',
            client_secret='MyDarkSecretInFacebook',
            name='facebook',
            authorize_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize',
            access_token_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
            base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/')

    @property
    def FacebookScope(self):
        return {
                'scope': 'public_profile,email',
                'response_type': 'code',
                'redirect_uri': self.getURL()
            }

    @property
    def googlePlus(self):
        return OAuth2Service(
            client_id='ThisCouldBeMyID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            client_secret='Idonthaveanysecrets',
            name='googlePlus',
            authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
            base_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')

    @property
    def GooglePlusScope(self):
        return  {
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read',
                'response_type': 'code',
                 'redirect_uri': self.getURL()
                }
```

as i said the most strange is that works fine with facebook, but, fail with google plus (i doble check the client_id and the client_secret and are correct) if it was a problem with the sockets facebook would have to fail too

ps.
I copy the rauth files in my project and the request files inside the rauth folder